# spring NonceExpiredException

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

I am using spring security 3.2.5. When i pass wrong or empty customer request parameter in the request, I get NonceExpiredException and returning me OK response. For other parameters my webservice is fine.

For example
http://localhost:8080/vtap/devices/?customer=&platform=Andriod

In above url customer parameter is empty. I am getting NonceExpiredException and returning empty OK response and request is not hitting webservice method. I am using spring restfull webservice.Instead of OK response I wanted 400 response.

Comment: that is your local url not the accessible internet url

Answer (score 0):

you can always write a Filter for normalizing your URL and response back **400** as you wish to user before Spring Security Filter even get started ~

Comment: Even the normalized url has same behavior. ..    http://localhost:8080/xx/devices%2F%3Fcustomer%3D%26platform%3DAndriod   ......Means customer parameter is conflicting with spring security digest Authentication.

Comment: you can always change a non parameter url with a abnormal url within the first filter for spring security to return 400 response

Comment: what if customer is invalid.. we can't check before auth.. It still showing same behaviour. My question is that customer parameter should not interfer  with authorization.

Comment: if you want to do so through the spring security, you should have write custom bean and inject it to your spring security descriptor~